# JQuery Get/Set currentTime "Radio Stations"

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

The effect I'm trying to achieve is that hovering on certain icons will play certain audio files. When you switch icons the new audio plays from the exact time that the last audio left off--this is supposed to be like you're changing channels on the radio.

The code below works, but only between two audio files, and they're bound to the same button.

How can I replicate this effect, but with 10 "stations," each with their own icon?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script>
    var events=["abort","canplay","canplaythrough","durationchange","emptied","ended",
        "error","loadeddata","loadedmetadata","loadstart","pause","play","playing",
        "progress","ratechange","readystatechange","seeked","seeking","stalled",
        "suspend","timeupdate","volumechange","waiting"]
    $(function(){
        var current={},
            audio=$("audio")
        audio.on("play",function(){
            current = this // remember 
        })
        $(".icon").hover(function(){
            var last=$(this).text()
            switch ( last ) {
                case "start":
                    audio.first().trigger("play")
                    $(this).text("switch")
                    break;
                case "switch":
                    var next=audio.not(current).prop("currentTime", current.currentTime).trigger("play")
                    audio.not(next).trigger("pause")
                    break
            }

        })
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="icon">start</div>

<audio class="radio1" controls> 
   <source src="assets/radio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio class="radio2" controls> 
   <source src="assets/radio2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g00dmhfh/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need add multi icons. You can control which is played by creating variables `current` and `next`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>perfect</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script>
    var events=["abort","canplay","canplaythrough","durationchange","emptied","ended",
        "error","loadeddata","loadedmetadata","loadstart","pause","play","playing",
        "progress","ratechange","readystatechange","seeked","seeking","stalled",
        "suspend","timeupdate","volumechange","waiting"]
    $(function(){
        var current = -1;
        var next = 0;
        var aAudio = $('audio');
        var audioLen = aAudio.length;
        $(".icon").click(function(){
                if(audioLen <= 0){
                return false;
            }else if(audioLen == 1){
                aAudio.eq(next).trigger('play');
            }else{
            if(current == -1){
                $(this).text("switch");
            }else{
                aAudio.eq(current).trigger('pause');
            }
            aAudio.eq(next).trigger('play');
            current = next;
                next = next == audioLen - 1?0:next+1;
            }
            console.log(current +'~~~~~'+ next);

        })
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="icon">start</div>
<div class="m-audio-wrap">
<audio class="radio1" controls> 
    <source src="assets/radio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio class="radio2" controls> 
    <source src="assets/radio2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio class="radio1" controls> 
    <source src="assets/radio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio class="radio2" controls> 
    <source src="assets/radio2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to get/set the selected audio playback from where the last left off? Also the multiple icons are so the user can select their channel.